# Samsung Galaxy S2 black screen

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-recovery

My Samsung Galaxy S2 turned off suddenly and it is not turning on any more.
If I put it for charging, it will heat up the device and not able to power on. All data stored in internal memory. Is there any way to get data back from device . USB also is not detecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your battery is broken or there is another hardware problem. You can do this; try to borrow a similar battery as the one used by your device, use it on your S2 and see if it turns on. If it does turn on then do a backup immediately.  If it doesn’t turn on then try connecting the device to your laptop and see if it is recognized. If it still doesn’t get recognized you better go to an authorized repair center but, there is still no assurance that the data can be recovered.